# Metaphorical equivalent of Timbuktu or Outer Mongolia

Tags: translation, metaphor

Does Japanese have any metaphorical equivalent to Timbuktu or Outer Mongolia (or, in the case of Australia, perhaps Woop Woop), meaning a remote or inaccessible place?

Wiktionary [recognises](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Timbuktu) the metaphorical meaning of Timbuktu, but doesn't have a translation for that into Japanese.

Comment: I found this one, http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%94%90%E5%A4%A9%E7%AB%BA but I imagine it's very uncommon these days so probably can't be considered an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think of anything, because...

Japanese indeed has a certain repertoire of metonymy that makes real names represent their prominent quality, such as:

> 今【いま】孔明【こうめい】 ([孔明](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhuge_Liang) is a most tactful strategist)
>   祇園【ぎおん】小町【こまち】 ([小町](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ono_no_Komachi) is a greatest beauty)
>   台風【たいふう】銀座【ぎんざ】 ([銀座](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginza) is a busiest downtown district)
>   東洋【とうよう】のパリ (パリ is...... you know?)

Those, however, only work in "as ... as X" method, and need a qualifier so that make it clear the mentioned one is not real X. You can much less let a proper name metaphorize an absolute notion; unlike in English, Timbuktu isn't a totally inaccessible town, Greek isn't an incomprehensible language, Xanadu isn't a utopia... In this sense, no proper name could be a real "synonym" of an idea in Japanese.

---

In a comment above, @Ciaran cited an interesting word 唐天竺の果て. Obviously, it's a word from an age when China and India was *literally* the end of the world they recognized. You can't seriously say it at the present time, as it doesn't even go beyond [this small circle](http://io9.gizmodo.com/more-than-half-of-the-worlds-population-lives-inside-t-493103044).

Answer (score 3):

Can I believe this example usage [found on Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Timbuktu&defid=891528)?

> We used to have each other over for dinner on a regular basis, but then she moved out to Timbuktu, and we haven't done it since.

Then perhaps there is no place name that can be used like this in Japanese. I can think of some typical and historical names for "extremely distant/inaccessible places" (such as [蝦夷地](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ezo) and [天竺](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tianzhu_(India))), but none of them can be used as metaphorically as this.

FWIW, in the last 10 years or so, 群馬県 (Gunma Prefecture) has often been treated like a land of mystery. See [this link](http://matome.naver.jp/odai/2133925662861896901) and [this **U**ncyclopedia article about 群馬](http://ja.uncyclopedia.info/wiki/%E7%BE%A4%E9%A6%AC%E7%9C%8C). This is a mere Internet meme, but I still sometimes see jokes about Gunma.

Comment: The example given on UD is a valid use of the expression.

Answer (score 2):

A couple I can think of:

> 最果ての地
>
> 秘境 ( or 秘境中の秘境)
>
> ど田舎

Comment: I wouldn't say any of these are similar usages (although the meaning is the same). I think the question is more specifically asking "is there a specific placename used in Japanese to refer to a remote area, like Timbuktu in English".

Answer (score 1):

Proverbial [Mecca] is the most happening place

> サーフィンのメッカといえばどこですか？ 　------> 　　ハワイのノースショアがメッカ中のメッカだと思います。 . . . . . . .  　　　日本はある意味たくさんありますが、毎日波が立ってるわけではありません　　その中で言うと千葉北の志田と千葉南の鴨川ですかね・・

Proverbial [Tibet] is the least happening place -- remote & cold, unsuitable for  agriculture, industry, or any development.  Nobody wants to live or visit there.  ( 辺境の代名詞 )

> 岩手県は日本のチベットと言われていますが . . . . . . . .  戦後、1950～1960年代には、山あいで交通の便が悪いことや、主な産業が新日本製鉄の釜石製鉄所位しかなく、所得水準が全国でも低いことから、「日本のチベット」と呼ばれてもいました。 日本では、交通の便の悪い山間地 ...

>  　　　日本のチベット」と言われる岩手県の中でも寒い所、 それで藪川を「日本のシベリア」と言う人もあるくらいである。

> そういえば、 . . . . . 区は「名古屋のチベット」と言われることが以前からよくありました。

>  　　　こんな勝浦のチベットと言われるほど山奥に どうしてケーキ屋さんがあるの？？？ でも、これが美味しいんです！！！